# Coil and PM Dimensional Ratios (BLDC)

Tags: design, brushless-dc-motor, coil, magnetic-flux

I am in the process of laying out coils for a Axial Brush less Motor. My question is - without taking turns or power into consideration. Are there any design ratios - which should be attempted. When seeking to a design a motor which is not specifically bias for torque or speed? I understand this may be a little iffy because PMs come in different strengths. But in general - are there any ratios or "rules of thumb" which one should consider for a balanced motor?

Such as PM diameter = coil inner diameter. PM surface area to coil surface area. PM diameter to Coil wall thickness etc. Or Coil Field to PM field?

I am about to start winding coils for a motor - and thought I would ask first before committing. As I am new to all of this. Below is a link to a 2-d drawing of the current pairing I came up with. The coils are 10-12mm tall. The PM is 30mm Diameter. I drew A - then realized the PM didn't fit well so I drew B. After drawing B - I now think I should get a PM that is slightly larger?

Full size: https://ibb.co/xLPGbzD

[image]

Comment: B looks fine.  Larger PM would require same shape coil.  Personally, I'd tweak coil shape so windings are aligned with two magnets.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Thanks, Gotcha - Yeah didnt even think about that. Glad you said something. Thats kind of important. Ill have to map out the full layout with coils and PMs and adjust accordingly.

Comment: It doesn't really have the answer I need yet, but you may find [my question here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/542931/producing-a-small-homemade-generator-with-reduced-cogging-torque) to be somewhat of use.